# Java - Default Switch Statement

Tags: switch-statement

I am writing some tests for a Java method which contains a switch statements but it seems that the "default statement" does not work. I only accept: Yes, No, Maybe. Everything else should return Maybe. My test always return the user input, does not matter what the user typed, so I guess my switch statement is not correct.

```
I have tried to move the default statement on the top

@Override
  public String choice(String ans) {
    getChoice = ans;
    switch (ans) {
      case "Yes":
        break;

      case "No":
        break;

      default:
        getChoice = "Maybe";
    }
    return getChoice;
}

Thank you!
```

Comment: This should work, how are you using it?  What are you overriding?

Answer (score 0):

Your switch should work... As Kyle tells you "what are you overriding ?"

But why a switch when you can perform an "if then else" ?

```
Public String choice (String choice) {
   If (choice.equals("yes") || choice.equals("no") {
      return choice;
   else {
      return "maybe";
   }
}
```

Switch is fine for multiple choices